# Undefined offset error 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code that will check if the month eg. january has a value of 0 and if its true it will execute the update query.

But i'am getting this error "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 "

```
$value_result = mysql_query("SELECT form_no FROM table_2014 WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($value_result)){
        if ( $row['january' == '0']){
            $sql = "UPDATE `table_2014` SET january = '$contri_amnt' WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Already contributed!";
            }
    }
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 5):

```
$row['january' == '0']
```

will return `$row[false]`, which is `$row[0]`

i think you meant

```
$row['january'] == '0'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use mysql_* functions anymore. They are deprecated + they are insecure because you wouldn't have to escape anything. I suggest you to use PDO instead and prepared statements.

You should do :

```
$value_result = mysql_query("SELECT form_no FROM table_2014 WHERE form_no = '".(int)$formnumber."'");
//guessin that the fields where all integers, since compareing against a "0"
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($value_result)) {
    if ( isset($row['january']) && $row['january'] == '0') {
        $sql = "UPDATE `table_2014` SET january = '".(int)$contri_amnt."' WHERE form_no = '".(int)$formnumber."'";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Already contributed!";
    }
}
```